Grafana LogQL: How can i count unique number of labels without grouping?
I want to get a unique count of user ID and display on Dashboard from my logs.
Example log stream:
ts=2022-09-16T10:52:54.21344541Z level=INFO UserID=65166 elapsed=2.364015ms
ts=2022-09-16T10:52:51.580617785Z level=INFO UserID=24413 elapsed=2.324235ms
ts=2022-09-16T10:52:48.947248244Z level=INFO UserID=65166 elapsed=2.818146ms
ts=2022-09-16T10:52:41.51854716Z level=INFO UserID=24413 elapsed=2.633352ms
ts=2022-09-16T10:51:14.584272582Z level=INFO UserID=24413 elapsed=2.04884ms
ts=2022-09-16T10:51:14.45564065Z level=INFO UserID=65166 elapsed=4.889566ms

I want to get a result of 2 because these are logs for 2 users - 65166 and 24413. I do not need to know the breakdown e.g. 65166 (3) , 24413 (3).
I am unable to use "SUM BY (userId)" because it generates a series per user and I am limited by 10K series.
